# Чи є росіянізмом слово «слід» (слідує)?

Tags: росіянізм

Чи коректне вживання слова «слід» до прикладу в таких реченнях:

> Для вступу до університету слід подати заяву і всі згадані далі документи.

Тлумачні словники також розділились у своїх значеннях. Частина яких запевняють, що це слово існує в українській мові, інші не згадують про значення цього слова як присудка.

Comment: Було б непогано вказати на ті «тлумачні словники».

Answer (score 3):

Просто [цитую](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B4) два основних тлумачних словника, що маємо на сьогодні:

1. СУМ:

> СЛІД 2, **присудк**. сл., також з інфін. Треба, необхідно, потрібно,
>   варто. [Любов:] Читала все, що під руку попадало..! [Орест:] Так і
>   слід. Літературу, як і життя, треба знати з усіх боків (**Леся Українка**,
>   II, 1951, 22); Іти їм слід було швидше, щоб до того, як завидніє,
>   прибитися до рибальських лісів (Григорій Тютюнник, Вир, 1964, 433);
>   Народну творчість, як і всю культуру взагалі, слід розглядати в
>   зв'язку з історією суспільства (Максим Рильський, III, 1956, 142);

Пані Косач я довіряю, але навіть якщо припустити якісь перекручення радянськими лінґвістами, то прошу до наступного джерела.

2. Словарь української мови: в 4-х тт. / За ред. Б. Грінченка.

> II. Слід, нар. Должно, слѣдуетъ. Не слід тобі лаятись. Ото воно так
>   жило, як слід. Рудч.

Обидва словника дають "слід" як присудок. Не бачу причини їм не довіряти.